# jQuery - Keep another element opened after mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

How do I keep a div from staying after mouseover? For example, I hover over one div, and then the other appears. When I try to hover over the one that has just been uncloaked, it disappears because I'm not ".mouseenter-ing," the original div.

### This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".panel").hide();
        $("body").fadeIn(1800);
        $(".starter").mouseover(function() {
            $(".panel").slideDown(600);
        });
        $(".starter").mouseleave(function() {
         $(".panel").slideUp(600);
            $(".panel").mouseenter(function() { 
                $(".panel").show();
      });
     });
    });
```

Comment: post your html as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the following:

- Mouse over .starter
- slideDown .panel
- Only when you mouse OUT of .panel, slideUp .panel

You are hiding .panel when you mouse out of .starter, try something like this instead starting on line 7:

```
$(".panel").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".panel").slideUp(600);
```

If you want to ensure .panel closes if they move off of .starter you could use a timer to ensure it eventually closes if they don't mouse over .panel in a specified amount of time.  In this case, 1 second:

```
$(".starter").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".panel").data('mouseLeaveTimeout', setTimeout(function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp(600);
  },1000));
});

$(".panel").mouseover(function() {
  clearTimeout($(this).data("mouseLeaveTimeout"));
});
```

Check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ookadoo/pen/YQrPwN) for an example of what I think you want.

Comment: Yes, that's almost exactly what I want. The only issue is, now, if my mouse leaves .starter without touching .panel, .panel stays there.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @ookadoo.
I made a new code, but I was wondering if you could keep the div open while hovered over.
`#dropdown` & `.something` are `<div>`s. 

When I hover over `#dropdown`, it hides. Whenever I exit `.something`, the entire menu closes. I'll PM you the code or something.

Comment: ` $(document).ready(function() {
$("#dropdown").hide();
$(".something").hover(function() {
$("#dropdown").slideToggle();
});
});
`

Comment: Your new code has different identifiers and it's not clear to me how it pertains to this specific question.  I added a codepen link that shows how the code I provided works.  Can you check that and mark my answer if it fits your original question?  If you have a new issue you're trying to resolve please add a new question.